# Django form and field validation does not work?

Tags: django, validation

When using the Django built-in Form classes the validation routine does not seem to work. 
The form consists simply of firstname and lastname. Firstname is required, and for testing purposes I check if lastname is Smith and raise an exception. When I violate those requirements **nothing happens**, i.e. **no exception** is being raised - after submitting the form the defined action (`POST` to `union/VIP_best/`) is simply triggered without any validation. The form is called at `union/contact/`, directed from `urls.py` to `views.ContactView.as_view()`

Here is my setup so far:
*views.py*

```
from union.forms import ContactForm
class ContactView(generic.edit.FormView):
    template_name = 'union/contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='Vorname', max_length=20, required=True, error_messages={'required': 'Please enter first name!'})
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Nachname', max_length=20)

def clean_lastname(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['lastname']
    if data != "Smith":
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your last name is not Smith.")
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your last name is Smith.")
    return data
```

*templates/union/contact.html*

```
<form action="/union/VIP_best/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**What am i missing so that the `.clean()` or `.is_valid` is being triggered?**
Do I have to explicitly call `Field.clean()` and `is_valid()`? If so, where?
The tutorials and Django documentation do not seem to mention anything the like.

Django 1.7, Python 3.4.2

Comment: Is the form on the `/union/VIP_best/` page? Or a different page?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I added that information (the form is on `/union/VIP_best/`).

Comment: Your form action should be itself. Meaning, if the form is on `/union/contact/`, you should be `POST`ing to `/union/contact/`

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Thanks! But how do I commit the POST data to the success_url? That is yet to find out. Probably not that hard...

Comment: Added my comment as an answer. It would be great if you could select it/close up this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be submitting to itself. Meaning, if the form is on `/union/contact/`, you should be `POST`ing to `/union/contact/`. Currently, you have it submitting to a different view/url.

The problem is arising because your form processing is happening in the `FormView`, not at your `success_url()`. You need to `POST` to the view that is actually responsible for the validation of the form (in this case, your `ContactView` at `/union/contact/`).

As a side note, it would probably be better to modify the action of the form to use `{% url 'your_form_url_name' %}`, as opposed to hard-coding the url into the template.